# Как, после получения урона персонажем, дать ему неуязвимость на время?

Tags: unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой:нужно сделать для игрока неуязвимость на определенное количество времени и это должно работать при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: В методе с получением урона сделай проверку на булевую переменную IsImmortal (например), а менять ее будешь по нажатию на кнопку. Запустив таймер или с помощью корутины вереншь в false

Comment: Тебе на Тостере уже ответили!

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool isInvulnerable;

private IEnumerator setInvulnerability (float time) {
    isInvulnerable = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    isInvulnerable = false;
}

private void onGetDamage () {
    if (!isInvulnerable) {
        // Получение урона только если НЕ неуязвимый
    }
}
```

setInvulnerability() вызывается c помощью `StartCoroutine(setInvulnerability());`

*P.S.:* В заголовке у вас написано, что неуязвимость после получения урона, в вопросе - по кнопке. В общем, я вам дал метод, а вызвать его можно и из OnClick и в конце onGetDamage() - где хотите.

*P.S. 2:* Ни в русском, ни в английском нет короткого слова для "неуязвимость", а Invulnerability - долго и легко опечататься, советую использовать предложенную Methorn переменную IsImmortal, ибо immortal - бессмертный